# What did I get wrong in solving a simple permutation problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

*Among 4 boys and 3 girls, let's pick 2 boys and 2 girls, and let them sit around a circle. How many ways are possible?*

There are $_4C_2=6$ ways to pick 2 boys out of 4, and $_3C_2=3$ ways to pick 2 girls out of 3. We now have 4 people chosen and there are $3!=6$ ways to arrange them in a circle. Thus I wrote as an answer $_4C_2\times_3C_2\times3!=6\times3\times6=108$, but the correct answer appears to be 54.

Am I missing something, or is the given answer incorrect?

Comment: One possible explanation is that the author considered mirror image arrangements to be the same. That is, $a b c d$ is treated as identical to $a d c b$, since each person has the same two neighhors in both orderings. But this is still a failure on the author's part, as the wording does not make this clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is correct. In fact, here are all the possible ways, each circle being listed such that the alphabetically smallest string appears first (i.e., among the equivalent circles `a, b, c, d`, `b, c, d, a`, `c, d, a, b` and `d, a, b, c`, the first one is chosen)

```
boy_1, boy_2, girl_1, girl_2
boy_1, boy_2, girl_1, girl_3
boy_1, boy_2, girl_2, girl_1
boy_1, boy_2, girl_2, girl_3
boy_1, boy_2, girl_3, girl_1
boy_1, boy_2, girl_3, girl_2
boy_1, boy_3, girl_1, girl_2
boy_1, boy_3, girl_1, girl_3
boy_1, boy_3, girl_2, girl_1
boy_1, boy_3, girl_2, girl_3
boy_1, boy_3, girl_3, girl_1
boy_1, boy_3, girl_3, girl_2
boy_1, boy_4, girl_1, girl_2
boy_1, boy_4, girl_1, girl_3
boy_1, boy_4, girl_2, girl_1
boy_1, boy_4, girl_2, girl_3
boy_1, boy_4, girl_3, girl_1
boy_1, boy_4, girl_3, girl_2
boy_1, girl_1, boy_2, girl_2
boy_1, girl_1, boy_2, girl_3
boy_1, girl_1, boy_3, girl_2
boy_1, girl_1, boy_3, girl_3
boy_1, girl_1, boy_4, girl_2
boy_1, girl_1, boy_4, girl_3
boy_1, girl_1, girl_2, boy_2
boy_1, girl_1, girl_2, boy_3
boy_1, girl_1, girl_2, boy_4
boy_1, girl_1, girl_3, boy_2
boy_1, girl_1, girl_3, boy_3
boy_1, girl_1, girl_3, boy_4
boy_1, girl_2, boy_2, girl_1
boy_1, girl_2, boy_2, girl_3
boy_1, girl_2, boy_3, girl_1
boy_1, girl_2, boy_3, girl_3
boy_1, girl_2, boy_4, girl_1
boy_1, girl_2, boy_4, girl_3
boy_1, girl_2, girl_1, boy_2
boy_1, girl_2, girl_1, boy_3
boy_1, girl_2, girl_1, boy_4
boy_1, girl_2, girl_3, boy_2
boy_1, girl_2, girl_3, boy_3
boy_1, girl_2, girl_3, boy_4
boy_1, girl_3, boy_2, girl_1
boy_1, girl_3, boy_2, girl_2
boy_1, girl_3, boy_3, girl_1
boy_1, girl_3, boy_3, girl_2
boy_1, girl_3, boy_4, girl_1
boy_1, girl_3, boy_4, girl_2
boy_1, girl_3, girl_1, boy_2
boy_1, girl_3, girl_1, boy_3
boy_1, girl_3, girl_1, boy_4
boy_1, girl_3, girl_2, boy_2
boy_1, girl_3, girl_2, boy_3
boy_1, girl_3, girl_2, boy_4
boy_2, boy_3, girl_1, girl_2
boy_2, boy_3, girl_1, girl_3
boy_2, boy_3, girl_2, girl_1
boy_2, boy_3, girl_2, girl_3
boy_2, boy_3, girl_3, girl_1
boy_2, boy_3, girl_3, girl_2
boy_2, boy_4, girl_1, girl_2
boy_2, boy_4, girl_1, girl_3
boy_2, boy_4, girl_2, girl_1
boy_2, boy_4, girl_2, girl_3
boy_2, boy_4, girl_3, girl_1
boy_2, boy_4, girl_3, girl_2
boy_2, girl_1, boy_3, girl_2
boy_2, girl_1, boy_3, girl_3
boy_2, girl_1, boy_4, girl_2
boy_2, girl_1, boy_4, girl_3
boy_2, girl_1, girl_2, boy_3
boy_2, girl_1, girl_2, boy_4
boy_2, girl_1, girl_3, boy_3
boy_2, girl_1, girl_3, boy_4
boy_2, girl_2, boy_3, girl_1
boy_2, girl_2, boy_3, girl_3
boy_2, girl_2, boy_4, girl_1
boy_2, girl_2, boy_4, girl_3
boy_2, girl_2, girl_1, boy_3
boy_2, girl_2, girl_1, boy_4
boy_2, girl_2, girl_3, boy_3
boy_2, girl_2, girl_3, boy_4
boy_2, girl_3, boy_3, girl_1
boy_2, girl_3, boy_3, girl_2
boy_2, girl_3, boy_4, girl_1
boy_2, girl_3, boy_4, girl_2
boy_2, girl_3, girl_1, boy_3
boy_2, girl_3, girl_1, boy_4
boy_2, girl_3, girl_2, boy_3
boy_2, girl_3, girl_2, boy_4
boy_3, boy_4, girl_1, girl_2
boy_3, boy_4, girl_1, girl_3
boy_3, boy_4, girl_2, girl_1
boy_3, boy_4, girl_2, girl_3
boy_3, boy_4, girl_3, girl_1
boy_3, boy_4, girl_3, girl_2
boy_3, girl_1, boy_4, girl_2
boy_3, girl_1, boy_4, girl_3
boy_3, girl_1, girl_2, boy_4
boy_3, girl_1, girl_3, boy_4
boy_3, girl_2, boy_4, girl_1
boy_3, girl_2, boy_4, girl_3
boy_3, girl_2, girl_1, boy_4
boy_3, girl_2, girl_3, boy_4
boy_3, girl_3, boy_4, girl_1
boy_3, girl_3, boy_4, girl_2
boy_3, girl_3, girl_1, boy_4
boy_3, girl_3, girl_2, boy_4
```

You can recreate the result by running the code below. The preprocessing part:

```
# Prepare input:
n_boys = 4
n_girls = 3

choose_boys = 2
choose_girls = 2

def make_group(size, prefix):
    return [prefix + str(x + 1) for x in range(size)]

group = make_group(n_boys, "boy_") + make_group(n_girls, "girl_")
```

And the actual looking for all good arrangements:

```
# Do the actual work:

from itertools import permutations
def starts_with_smallest(permutation):
    first = permutation[0]
    for item in permutation[1:]:
        if item < first:
            return False
    return True

def correct_numbers(permutation, expect_boys, expect_girls):
    n_boys = 0
    n_girls = 0
    for member in permutation:
        if member.startswith('boy'):
            n_boys += 1
        elif member.startswith('girl'):
            n_girls += 1
        else:
            raise Exception("invalid input")
    return n_girls == expect_girls and n_boys == expect_boys

def valid(permutation, expect_boys=2, expect_girls=2):
    return correct_numbers(permutation, expect_boys, expect_girls) and starts_with_smallest(permutation)

for item in permutations(group, 4):
    if valid(item):
        print(', '.join(item))
```

Comment: I would assume the original question intended mirror cycles (for example, "boy_3, girl_3, girl_2, boy_4" and "boy_3, boy_4, girl_2, girl_3") to be excluded, since this is double the given answer.

Comment: The lecturer accepted the original question having an error. Thanks.